# Authenticate multiple tenants using OpenIddict

Tags: openiddict

We have working proof of concept of application which is composed of four main subsystems:

- spa
- bff (YARP)
- api
- oidc (openiddict) which is also behing reverse proxy and on the same main domain

Each tenant recognized by subdomain. Everything works fine on static configuration for one tenant. Now we need to make it dynamic.

Registration new tenant should reflect to create some changes in oidc but we do not know which path we should take:

1. register as many clients as tenants but bff will need to know of all registrations too - not so special case :/
2. register one bff client and based on some tenantId (subdomain) dynamically change:

   - token generation process
   - RedirectUris
   - PostLogoutRedirectUris

I think that second option will be the best but how to do it with OpenIddict?